# Can i spread an Array of parameter names into a function declaration

Tags: javascript

I have an object which returns,

```js
[
    {
        name:"getSpeed",
        params:["distance","time"]
    },
    {
        name:"getTime",
        params:["speed","distance"]
    },
    ...
]
```

This object is subject to change as it is gathered from an embedded device.

im trying to convert this into an object with callable functions i.e.

```js
let myObj = {
    getSpeed: function(distance, time){
        /* do something (this is irrelevant) */
    },
    getTime: function(speed, distance){
        /* do something (again not relevant) */
    }

}
```

is there any way to map an array of strings to function parameters when mapping over an array?

Comment: No because there is no point in doing that... you would need to know those variables by names anyway if you want to refer to them inside of the function... so the "irrelevant" part is actually very relevant.

Comment: @CherryDT it is irrelevant as the code that would be places where the comments are would be something along the lines of `this.UART.write(functionName(paramValues))` this object is just calling the functions on a device where they are already declared, the array of objects with the name and params keys is what is returned by the device

Comment: JavaScript with actual `function`s would help us to help you. See [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: @cllmmclu But, see, how would you write this code in advance if the param values are known only at runtime? Can you give a more exact example of how the code could look like? Right now it sounds as if the functions would have to exist as global variables, for `this.UART.write(getSpeed(distance, time))` to work... Depending on what you do there, you may not even need any of the parameter names, just forward all arguments (`function (...args) { this.UART.write(something(...args)) }`)

Comment: It would be helpful to see a full example of how the resulting object should look like, including the actual function bodies as you'd expect them for each of the different functions. I feel like I almost understand what you need and could write an answer, but I'm not sure how to properly apply it to your situation, because this info is missing.

Comment: @CherryDT I was thinking about using ...args but didnt want the option of sending too many parameters. 

say the device has `function getSpeed(distance,time){return distance * time}` my intention is to be able to send `this.UART.write('getSpeed(100,10)')` to the device. and for this to be callable through `myObj.getSpeed(100,10)` on the web side of things but ideally only if getSpeed exists and if the number of params are correct

Comment: Ah - OK, your original example had the quotes missing. How would strings and other types like objects, arrays, etc. be passed, or are only numbers supported?

Comment: @CherryDT assuming a method `capitalizeName` existed it would be called as `this.UART.write('capitalizeName("name")')`

Comment: @CherryDT or even just using a .toString() at the end of the argument

Comment: That would make `,` and `)` ambiguous. Anyway, writing an answer.

Comment: @CherryDT the embedded device expects javascript written in a string, it evaluates this on the other end using an eval(), i know this is less than ideal but its just what I have to work with sadly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comments it appears you want to create functions from this definition which send commands with a function-call-like string which is `eval`ed on the other side, and you don't actually care about the paramater names but rather about the correct number of parameters.

I would therefore recommend something like this:

```js
const myObj = Object.fromEntries(data.map(({ name, params }) => [
  name,
  (...args) => {
    if (args.length !== params.length) {
      throw new TypeError(`${name} expected ${params.length} arguments, got ${args.length}`)
    }
    
    this.UART.write(`${name}(${args.map(arg => JSON.stringify(arg)).join(',')})`)
  }
]))
```

This will work with all the datatypes that JSON supports, and will as a side effect also pass `undefined` as argument correctly.

Here is a runnable example with `console.log` instead of `this.UART.write`:

```js
const data = [
    {
        name: "getSpeed",
        params: ["distance", "time"]
    },
    {
        name: "getTime",
        params: ["speed", "distance"]
    }
]


const myObj = Object.fromEntries(data.map(({ name, params }) => [
  name,
  (...args) => {
    if (args.length !== params.length) {
      throw new TypeError(`${name} expected ${params.length} arguments, got ${args.length}`)
    }

    console.log(`${name}(${args.map(arg => JSON.stringify(arg)).join(',')})`)
  }
]))

myObj.getSpeed(123, 456) // prints `getSpeed(123,456)`
myObj.getTime(123, 456) // prints `getTime(123,456)`
myObj.getTime("hello", true) // prints `getTime("hello",true)`
myObj.getTime(1) // throws `getTime expected 2 arguments, got 1`
```

However, as you said yourself, the whole `eval` business is not ideal anyway. I would recommend - if possible - to reconsider the protocol to use something more secure and robust like [gRPC](https://grpc.io/) or, one layer below, [protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers). Given that you are using JavaScript on both ends, [JSON-RPC](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-rpc-2.0) could also be a nice solution.